statsmodels qqplot doesn't match when using fit=True and scipy.stats.dist.fit
I was researching how quantile-quantile plots work and came across the following inconsistency:
I was trying to compare quantiles from uniformerly distributed sample against normal distribution quantiles. First, I use normal distribution parameters obtained from loc, scale = scipy.stats.norm.fit(sample), and making qqplot with frozen scipy.stats.norm(loc=loc, scale=scale). Then I make qqplot with just scipy.stats.norm and fit=True. Documentation on qqplots says that it uses dist.fit under the hood, but plots I got is significantly different!
Ticks on y and x axis are seem to be incorrect in the second case. In the first case, the y-axis ticks are in the range from 0 to 2, and in the second - from -1.5 to 1.5.
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import scipy.stats as stats

rng = np.random.default_rng()
sample = rng.uniform(low=0, high=2, size=(100,))
loc, scale = stats.norm.fit(sample)    # 1.04, 0.56

fig = sm.qqplot(sample, stats.norm(loc=loc, scale=scale))

fig = sm.qqplot(sample, stats.norm, fit=True)

The first plot using stats.norm(loc=loc, scale=scale)
The second plot using stats.norm, fit=True
What am I doing wrong?

Are you fitting uniform RV with normal?!? Why?

I'm just experimenting
